# How do i load a new xib on an orientation change on the ipad?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do i load a new xib on an orientation change on the ipad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rotation method, like willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration, you can call initWithNibName:bundle on a UIViewController or something like:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:name owner:self options:nil];
```

Comment: where is that method or do i have to write it myself and if so where is there documentation on how to write it

Comment: I assume you mean the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: method.  That is part of the UIViewController class.  You can override that in your view controller.  Check out the topic "Creating an Alternate Landscape Interface" at this link: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html